# Implementing SEO for a Zend Framework/PHP/Angular.js application

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework, seo

A team has implemented a web application using MySql, PHP with the Zend framework and Angular.js on the client side. I am in charge of implementing the SEO for this application.

I understand I have to take HTML snapshots of the Angular pages and serve them to web crawlers. That's the only solution working for search engines not executing Javascript.

1. How can I take such snapshots efficiently? I mean, is there a PHP-related tool that can help me? Should I call a tool from PHP? If yes, which one?
2. Had this application been developed with `node.js`, I might have used something like Grunt's `grunt-html-snapshot`. Is there an equivalent for the Zend framework?
3. Would you recommend I take snapshots once for all, or should I generate them dynamically? The content of the website does not change that often. It is not critical to have the latest content for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally depends on your application. I've seen a few commercial solutions:

https://prerender.io middleware, which works with Zend Framework2. It's free for under 250 "pages" and works if 7-day caching is acceptable.

Also, check out Brombone.

If you want to go manual, you'll need to do a few things (details [here](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/serious-angular-seo.html)):

- Set up hashbang (#!) syntax and HTML5 mode with `$location` service
- Add `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` to your html header, which tells Google (and others) to crawl the site using the `?_escaped_fragment_=` tag
- You can then parse the escaped fragment on the backend to serve some sort of static rendering